# Angular Gantt chart with days and dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gantt-chart

I do not know angular js & i am using angular gantt chart from here https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt & this chart shows dates but not days(Su, Mo,Tu.. etc). Changing the scale is not helping. So what can i do to show days in angular gantt chart.

If i need to make changes in the code please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436685) if not the same.

However, to summarize what was stated there and what I have found by experience, you want to use the headers-formats attribute in combination with the headers attribute on the gantt directive.

```
var options = {
  headers: ['month', 'day'],
  headersFormats: {
    month: 'MMM',
    day: 'dd'
  } 
}
```

That should do what you want it to do.  The scale just changes the increments of the columns ('days', 'weeks', 'months', etc...).

For more information, see the documentation for angular-gantt and more specifically the documentation for the [headers-formats](https://www.angular-gantt.com/configuration/attributes/#headers-formats) attribute.